# data being loaded does load until after the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on an application that pulls the current user to use as the default user. Using React 16.

So I am having a problem that I can't seem to find the solution to, hopefully fresher eyes than mine might be able to see a way to handle this.  But first a little React knowledge.

React works in components.  When a component is called, it has a couple of stages that it goes through before actually displaying any code.

- **constructor** - the component is initiated, any data/structures that the component needs are created here.
- **componentDidMount** -- once the component is created, they this where the data that it needs is loaded.  For example, if you needed to display a list of items, those items would be loaded here.
- **render** - this is where the html is created for the component is built.  This is what displays things in the browser.

Obviously there is a lot more going on under the covers than just this, but this is sufficient for illustration purposes.

So my problem is I need to default some input in the render to show data that is supposedly loaded in the componentDidMount.  But that doesn't seem to be happening.  Instead, the data that I need is being loaded after the render.

I feel that either I am not understanding correctly how React does these things, or I need to create some sort of delay to allow the data to load completely before the render.

Can someone help me, direct me to a resource that could help, or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The short answer is - once the data loads, you have to save in the component's state. When you do that, the component automatically re-renders and has access to the updated state. If this does not help, then the main question is - have you gone through React's basic tutorial yet? If not, do that. After you're comfortable with the basic concepts, search for "how to fetch data in React" and read a few articles. E.g. at first glance this article seems to explain what you need to know: https://blog.logrocket.com/patterns-for-data-fetching-in-react-981ced7e5c56/. Might as well read it : ]

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, i understood that.  So i guess my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Solved the problem, though, but using an async call to the api that returns the data i need.  I had to do it this way, rather than through the react-redux architecture.  So i need to study ho the application uses redux in more detail.